# Git push error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain.com[:7555]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: git, ssh, git-push

I can't seem to use Git to push to the server. However, I can SSH to the box.
I can't figure out why:

```
$ cat .git/config   
[core]  
    repositoryformatversion = 0  
    filemode = true
    bare = false  
    logallrefupdates = true  
    ignorecase = true  
[remote "server_idm"]  
    url = ssh://username@domain.com[:7555]/home/username/repo_Project/  
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/server_idm/*
```

$ git push server_idm

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain.com[:7555]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known fatal:  
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, I can easily SSH to the box.
$ ssh -p 7555 username@domain.com

```
Linux servername 2.6.32.9-rscloud #6 SMP Thu Mar 11 14:32:05 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS  

Welcome to Ubuntu!  

Last login: Mon Oct 25 21:22:44 2010 from 8.17.58.38  
username@servername Tue Oct 26 14:01:59 ~   
$ exit  
logout  
Connection to domain.com closed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets in the URL.

Comment: In documentation [] often means "this bit is optional"